# How can i pass parametres from vue function in component?

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, function-parameter

I've to call a function with parametres but i didn't find a correct solution for my problem. The NavigateTo should pass a String value to my index to switch it and navigate to the correct component(no vue router).

**Home.js**

```
Vue.component('Home', {
    props: ['visible','logged'],
    data: function (){
        return{

        }
    },
    template: <a class="btn btn-primary display-4" on:click="NavigateTo(accedi)">Accedi</a>\n' 
    (only the button that call the function,i will post the rest of the code only if necessary)
    methods:{
        NavigateTo:function(destination){
            this.$emit('transit-inner', destination);
        }
    }
});
```

**Index.js**

```
<section id="Home" style="margin-top: 60px">
    <Home v-bind:visible="visible" v-bind:logged="session_info" v-on:transit-inner="goto()"></Home>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#Home',
            data:{
                visible: routes.visible_home,
                session_info: routes.status_session
            },
            methods:{
                goto: function (destination){
                    alert(destination);
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an Inline Event Handler (`goto()`) in your template:

```html
<Home v-bind:visible="visible" v-bind:logged="session_info" v-on:transit-inner="goto()"></Home>
```

You've two options:

One, remove the `()`

```html
<Home v-bind:visible="visible" v-bind:logged="session_info" v-on:transit-inner="goto"></Home>
```

Or, provide the `$event` special variable if using Inline Handler

```js
<Home v-bind:visible="visible" v-bind:logged="session_info" v-on:transit-inner="goto($event)"></Home>
```

Comment: alert still show undefined

Comment: resolved: i used the second option but the problem was the cache